# In OAuth2, does the Authorization Server send the auth code directly to the Client, or to the Client through the Resource Owner?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

Relevant section in docs: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.1

Initially it says:

> The authorization code is obtained by using an authorization server as
> an intermediary between the client and resource owner.  Instead of
> requesting authorization directly from the resource owner, the client
> directs the resource owner to an authorization server (via its
> user-agent as defined in [RFC2616]), **which in turn directs the
> resource owner back to the client with the authorization code**.

The bolded part makes me think that the Auth code is given to the Resource Owner, which then gives it to the Client. Like so:

[image]

However, it later says:

> The authorization code provides a few important security benefits,
> such as the ability to authenticate the client, **as well as the
> transmission of the access token directly to the client without
> passing it through the resource owner's user-agent and potentially
> exposing it to others, including the resource owner.**

This makes me think that the auth code is being sent *directly* to the Client, rather than passing through the Resource Owner. Like so:

[image]

Which of the two is it? And if it's the latter, then what is the response that the Resource Owner gets?

Comment: When they say "user-agent as defined in RFC2616" (literally an HTTP header) they mean "user agent" (browser), right?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing the authorization code with the access token.
In the first part the RFC says that the authorization code is passed from the authorization server to the resource owner and then passed from the resource owner (via its user-agent) to the client.
It later says that the ACCESS TOKEN (used to obtain information) is realesed directly to the client. That's because at first the client obtains the authorization code from the user-agent of the resource owner, then it exchanges it for the access token with the authorization server. Obviously this happens in the authorization code grant. In the implicit grant it's all different.